# ODATA: How to get items by a list of id's

Tags: api, odata

I want to load items via odata passing a list of id's. For example I should do that to load the item with id 1:

`GET http://localhost:9001/DefaultBatch/DefaultBatchCustomer(1) HTTP/1.1`

Now I would like to do something like that to load the items with id 1 and 2:

`GET http://localhost:9001/DefaultBatch/DefaultBatchCustomer(1,2) HTTP/1.1`

Is it possible to do? I don't find any information in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do filtering by multiple IDs, you have to use the `$filter` clause:

```
GET http://localhost:9001/DefaultBatch/DefaultBatchCustomer?$filter=id eq 1 or id eq 2
```

[OData URI conventions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html) / Logical operators paragraph

Comment: Ok, you are right. And to do a PUT or PATCH of more entities?

Comment: @MrScf Excerpt from that same document: "The semantics of system query options applied to POST requests to entity sets as well as all PATCH, PUT and DELETE requests are not defined by this specification and are reserved for future versions." I guess it then depends on your OData implementation.

Comment: I am getting OPTIONS 404 not found. I would like to pass the ids as array.[FromODataUri] long[] keys . But the request doesn't find any valid endpoint.